# Statsd + Graphie , showinglow fequency events

Tags: graphite, statsd

I am using the stadard [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) + [Statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/) stack. A 10 sec statsD interval + 10s graphite retention schema.

I have several events that happen 1K - 10K times a day. And I would like to show them in a graph too. But the graph is too flat (24h range of statsD has 8640 slots). I would like to show a graph that measures my event in like events/min , or events/5min - the default right now is events / 10s . Is that possible wihouth changing the default statsd interval and retention schemas in graphite.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer the built in function [summarize](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) in graphite does exactly that.